# How to add/subtract from a number that comes from a php variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

What I am trying to do is update a Total Price based on select options. The initial price amount comes from a session variable. I have gotten the variable to pass into Javascript, but i can not seem to add/subtract from that number when using the form.

What am I missing?

thanks for the help.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   

var phonePrice = "<?php echo $q2; ?>";
var total = phonePrice;

function calcTotal()
{
    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        //This happens for each checked input field
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        total += parseInt(value); 
    });
}

//This happens when the page loads
calcTotal();    
$("form").before('<p class="total">Total: <strong>' + total + '</strong></p>');
$(":submit").before('<p class="total">Total: <strong>' + total + '</strong></p>');

$("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function()
{
    total = phonePrice;
    calcTotal();
    $("p.total").html("Total: <strong>" + total + "</strong>");
});
    });
    </script>
```

The Form looks like this

```
    <form action="" method="post">
<fieldset id="delivery_speed">
    <legend>Options
    </legend><ol>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="speed" id="speed_1day" value="49" />
            <label for="speed_1day">Option 1 ($49)</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="speed" id="speed_3days" value="0" checked />
            <label for="speed_3days">Option 2 (no charge)</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="speed" id="speed_5days" value="-39" />
            <label for="speed_5days">Option 3 (-$39)</label>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset> 
<fieldset id="browser_support">
    <legend>Additional Choices</legend>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="browser" id="browser" value="100" />
        <label for="browser">Checkbox 1 ($100)</label>
    </p>
</fieldset>
<p><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Continue to Checkout &gt;&gt;"></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Assuming the number is passed in correctly to the variable `phonePrice` please show the rendered HTML/JS (with an actual value, instead of the `<?php /*...*/ ?>`). Also: when using `parseInt()` you should use a radix, for the decimal system: `parseInt(value,10)`.

Comment: How about dropping the quotes that initialize `phonePrice` as a string literal? `var phonePrice = <?php echo $q2; ?>`;

Answer (score 2):

```
var phonePrice = "<?php echo $q2; ?>";
```

assuming that the php code spits out something like this when rendered:

```
var phonePrice = "99.99";
```

The quotes make it a string and not a number. Remove the quotes and you will have a number that will add correctly.

```
var phonePrice = <?php echo $q2; ?>;
```

Comment: I tried removing the quotes from the variable, but when i do that the price does not show on page load

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to find another way that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from `phonePrice`:

```
var phonePrice = <?php echo $q2; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when you do `total += parseInt(value)`. Since you define `phonePrice` as

```
var phonePrice = "<?php echo $q2; ?>";
```

it does string concatenation but not sum.

You should either unquote the value

```
var phonePrice = <?php echo $q2; ?>;
```

or add another type conversion:

```
var phonePrice = parseInt("<?php echo $q2; ?>", 10);
```